# How can I verify login using google api, oauth?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, google-api, google-oauth

I want to use google oauth api to log in to the site which I create.

I use `react` and `node` and I'm done with getting current access_token issued but I'm not sure how to know if the user is logged in.

- Should I check the user's access_token every time the user calls the api of my site?
- If that's correct, should the access_token be held by the client?
- Isn't that a security issue?

I did a lot of searching but I don't know how to manage access_token and how to check if user is logged in.

This is the [article](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) I referenced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I check the user's access_token every time the user calls the
>   api of my site?

Yes. The only ones you will not check will the public ones.

> If that's correct, should the access_token be held by the client?

Yes, it can be stored in cookies, local storage... Is is debatable which is the best solutions, you can articles such as [this](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) one

> Isn't that a security issue?

No. Anybody can check the content of a JWT token (just paste the content [here](https://jwt.io/)). But the neat thing is that it can't be modified or manipulated. Of course, it is advisable to keep it as safe as a password, so don't share it around :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a few more questions, what's the difference between id_token and access_token? The id_token seems to be jwt, so I saved it in the http header on the client and validated that value when calling the api, but I don't know how to reissue it when the id_token expires. It's access_token to be refreshed with refresh_token?

Comment: id_token is used to identify that a user signed in. access_token is when requesting resources if he actually has the appropriate rights for it (for example a regular user can't access other user's data or cannot access admin functionality). They usually all are JWT tokens (depends on the implementation).

Comment: id_token is just to get user info - https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-tokens#id-token-lifetime Access token is the one you need to check on every API call. With the refresh token (usually expires in days or even months), you can get a new access token (expires in 30mins). Indentity usually expires in 10h.

Comment: 1.' They usually all are JWT tokens' You said, but access_token doesn't seem to be jwt. access_token is 'ya..' string and could be not be verified on the jwt.io site. So I don't know how to check access_token in my backend so I used id_token. In addition, I only handle login and sign up with google id, no need to call google's api. But should I always check when calling api with access_token? Can't I check with id_token?
2. If we check with id_token, how should it be refreshed when id_token expires? Thanks for your kind reply

Comment: It may be that the library is set to generate an opaque instead of JWT access token - https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-tokens Still, you need to use that for authorisation, not the identity token. The identity token refresh depends on the library again, it may or may not be refreshed using the refresh token.